# Media converter - Coax or Twisted Pair

Tags: ethernet, plc, coax

I am working on a Double Leaf Bascule bridge spanning across a river that needs rehabilitated. The bridge is driven from a ControlLogix PLC consisting of 4 racks on the nearside span. Power/control is sent to the farside span via a single submarine cable installed in 1987. We are attempting to install a 5th I/O rack on the farside span to control various relays/encoders. The problem is there's no ethernet cable inside the submarine cables for the farside I/O rack. The options are to use either a Coaxial cable (RG-11) or a shielded twisted pair. Could we install a media converter on both spans (ethernet->coax->ethernet) to communicate with the farside I/O rack?

Comment: depends on the bandwidth you need. If you are within what that cable can handle it's no problem.

Comment: also, there's plenty control / PLC interfaces which are *meant* to be used with differential pair rather than full ethernet – you don't really need a *network* bus if you really just want to actuate a few relays on the far end, rather a reliable control link, e.g. based on RS485.

Comment: [Yesterday](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/421914/11683), you said, *"modifying existing/installing a new submarine cable is not an option."* What changed? If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.